# How to avoid share of variable across different user in singleton Class

Tags: java, servlets, singleton

```
  public class CompanyServlet extends HttpServlet
    {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static org.apache.log4j.Logger  log = Logger.getLogger(Company.class);

/**
 * This string holds the filename of the file.
 */
String fileName = null;
Details detailsById = null;

    Page page = null;
String date = null;
HttpServletRequest request = null;

/**
 * This holds the bytes of the file to be written .
 */
Workbook wb = null;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doPost(request, response);
}

public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}


public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

    }
```

The class CompanyServlet is a singleton, so the member field request is shared between users. The result is that one user could see another user's data. How to avoid this problem.

Comment: Err, that would be the point of having a singleton. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't keep state in servlets, keep them in the session if you need to store them somewhere.

Comment: anywhere else u mean in some other class ?

Comment: No, the HTTP session.

Comment: could u plz explain a bit in detail , i m not getting exactly :(